# paypal express checkout re-render

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have a simple payment form on my site and I am using paypal express checkout .

The amount to be charged looks like it needs to be set when the page loads.
What if the client switches something in their cart and the amount to charge needs to be changed.
How can I re-render the button again?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to re-render the button to change the cart amount, if you're using the latest button. The `payment()` function is only called on button click, so you can decide the amount at the last possible second.

Comment: When the page loads, I have to hard code the total amount in there. I tried doing something with jquery like $('#totalamt').val() but it caused the paypal to error

Comment: That would be a better way to do it. What was the error from paypal?

Comment: Error: [object XMLHttpRequest]
./node_modules/post-robot/src/drivers/receive/types.js/_RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE[__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__conf__.a.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.RESPONSE]@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2021:118
receiveMessage@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1928:21
messageListener@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1948:13

Comment: Can you paste the error from the http call to paypal, in the chrome network tab?

Comment: That's the error i get in the console when I click the paypal button

Comment: Right -- but if you look in the network tab, you should see a failed request to paypal. The response should have more details about what went wrong.

Comment: Can you get the response text? This should give a clue about the error

Comment: @user1899829 did you figure this out? Same issue here, want to keep the custom field in sync with something on the page.